# How can I create a recursive template to loop over the data contained in a type?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a type containing some data and I want to loop over the data in the type and dynamically allocate memory in an array based on the data. It's a bit hard to explain exactly what I mean, so some code should help. Here is my best attempt so far:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

//int wrapper
template<int n>
struct Int{
    static const int value = n;
};

//list of types
template<typename... Ts>
struct MyContainer{
    using Data = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    static const int N = sizeof...(Ts);
    
    template<int n>
    using Nth = typename std::tuple_element<n, Data>::type;
};

//used to allocate memory for MyStruct::array
template<typename DataType>
struct MemoryAllocator{
    template<int i>
    static void exec(char **array){
        using T = typename DataType::Nth<i>;
        const int n = T::value;
        array[i] = new char[n];
    }
};

//template-based "for loop"
struct Looper{
    template<typename DataType, template<typename T> typename Executor, int start, int end, typename... ArgTs>
    static void loop(ArgTs... args...){
        Executor<DataType>::exec<start>(args...);
        if constexpr(start < end){
            loop<DataType, Executor, start+1, end, ArgTs...>(args...);
        }
    }
};

template<typename DataType>
struct MyStruct{
    MyStruct(){
        const int n = DataType::N;
        array = new char*[n];
        Looper::loop<DataType, MemoryAllocator, 0, n-1>(array);
    }

    char **array;
};

int main(){
    using MyDataType = MyContainer<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>>;
    MyStruct<MyDataType> s;
}
```

I am defining the type `MyDataType` as a type containing three `Int`s containing 1, 2, 3. I want to create an instance of `MyStruct<MyDataType>` and have the constructor of this type initialise a 2D `char` array, consisting of arrays of length 1, 2, 3. To do this, I tried to create a recursive template to iterate over the three `Int` types, pull out the underlying `int`s, and allocate the memory. However, I get the following errors (with g++ 10.1):

```cpp
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Looper::loop(ArgTs ..., ...)’:
main.cpp:34:48: error: expected binary operator before ‘)’ token
   34 |         Executor<DataType>::exec<start>(args...);
      |                                                ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void Looper::loop(ArgTs ..., ...) [with DataType = MyContainer<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3> >; Executor = MemoryAllocator; int start = 0; int end = 2; ArgTs = {char**}]’:
main.cpp:46:56:   required from ‘MyStruct<DataType>::MyStruct() [with DataType = MyContainer<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3> >]’
main.cpp:54:26:   required from here
main.cpp:34:33: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
   34 |         Executor<DataType>::exec<start>(args...);
      |                             ~~~~^~~~~~
```

Also, I would ideally like to not have to define the `MemoryAllocator` struct at all and instead use some sort of templated lambda function, but I'm not sure that it's possible, and it's not really a problem if it isn't.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: **tl;dr** of the dupe: `Executor<DataType>::template exec<start>(args...);` and `typename DataType::template Nth<i>;` - you were missing a `template` keyword on access to those dependent templates.

Comment: There is also another problem: the declaration of `Looper::loop`: the arguments are `ArgTs... args...`, that is a variadic list of `args` arguments and a following list (the second `...`) of variadic C-style arguments. I don't think is what do you want; I suppose you want only the first variadic list so you have to remove the second `...`